# How to integrate Sagepay iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, swift, payment-gateway, opayo

According to my application requirement, I need to integrate the Sagepay ios SDK, but on the Sagepay website, they don't provide any official document or flow also.

I try and get some code in the objective-c mode in here

https://github.com/ColorsSoftwarePvtLtd/SagePay-iOS

Please refer to me any SDK example codes in Swift or already existing links.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a third party project I reckon that's not an official SagePay supported SDK.

If app integration is extremely important to you, don't use SagePay and instead use modern providers like Stripe/Braintree/Adyen who generally provide SDKs and have better documentation / examples.

The support for mobile payments from SagePay is painful. We asked them for a ApplePay / GooglePay integration back in 2017 and they said then that they "are working on it".  We've since gone with a different provider for those types of payments, and we're quite glad we did otherwise we'd still be waiting 2.5 years later.

At the moment for classic card payments we submit payment details to SagePay and then go to a WebView for 3-D Secure, which we've had to manage in our apps. There is unfortunately no nice SDK to use. For iOS there is this https://github.com/brightec/3DSecureView which helps somewhat with that.

HTH.